# Using QNetworkAccessManager offline

Tags: qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

My application consists from two apps. And one of them may ask another to perform some commands through a REST call (call an URL on localhost). For this purposes we use `QNetworkAccessManager` (for put, get and post request).

Now there is a problem - device may go offline sometimes and when he does it - for some reason we can't use rest calls through access manager. It seems that it happen when network configuration that it uses is destroyed (like disabling Wifi adapter etc). When this configuration is restored (enabled Wifi), access manager starts work again.

Another detail - when we start app while we are offline - it works regardless of online state. It may be related to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#network-and-roaming-support).

This reproduces on both Win and Mac.

So the question is how can i reliably use QNetworkAccessManager for this purposes irregardless of devices online state? We use this manager only for localhost REST calls. What default network configuration or behavior should i set?

Example of usage below:

```
mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "AppName/1.0");
request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
*reply = mNetManager->get(request);
```

Edit: online state is not required, since i need this access manager only for accessing local URLs on browser

Comment: It is definitely related to bearer management. Does it work if you move your platform's bearer plugin out of the way?

Comment: @peppe thanks for you response and sorry for long answer from my side. This bug appears both with qt's bearer plugin and without it. Though it seems that bearer plugin increases reproduce rate of this bug (almost every single time instead of sometimes). Unfortunately i cannot really remove it, since i need Qt's functionality for detecting online state for other part of app. And it requires bearer plugin

Comment: @peppe it apperas you were right. As soon as i removed libqcorewlanbearer from deploy script - problem dissapeared and performance have increased. It appears that this plugin is really bugged for qt 5.5.1 - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50181 and causes a lot more problems then ones i found. If you post it as answer, i'll accept it, since it was you who guessed right from the start

Comment: For those who this is an option for: this issue is [fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59219) for 5.9.2.

Comment: @Morten242 thanks! That's exactly the issue. I just knew that something fishy was going on but could not put it all together

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can force network accessibility to get local content:

```
mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "AppName/1.0");
request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
mNetManager->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible); // <--
auto reply = mNetManager->get(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `QNetworkAccessManager` have stuff for network availability. Why not using it?

```
QNetworkAccessManager * mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(mNetManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessibleChanged,
        this, &YourClass::slotExecutedWhenNetworkAccessibilityChanges);

NetworkAccessibility netAcc = mNetManager->networkAccessible();

switch (netAcc) {
    case QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible:
        // You are online.
        break;

    case QNetworkAccessManager::NotAccessible:
        // You are offline.
        break;

    case QNetworkAccessManager::UnknownAccessibility:
    default:
        // You know nothing, Jon Snow.
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, i am aware of this. The point of this question is to use reliably networkAccessManager in any condition. Since it's not required to be online to connect to localhost REST server. But for some reason, when online state changes to offline or machine goes to sleep (which cause network devices to change) i loose any connection whatsoever